# Flutter set Page View Builder height based on device display size setting

Tags: flutter, responsiveness, flutter-pageview, sized-box

I am applying a `PageView.builder` in a `SingleScrollView` in my project and it requires me to give it a fixed height where I wrapped it with a `SizedBox` with a given height after that. However, when I change the display size in the device settings, the widget looks a bit off from what I am expecting. For example, if I change the display size to a smaller value, there will have a large space in my widget because I fixed the `SizedBox`'s height. So, my problem is, is there any way to set the height of the `SizedBox` based on the child widget's height? I have tried fixing the height using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * heightRatio` but it still cannot help me when I change to different display size in my phone. The following is my sample code:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Padding(
          padding: bodyPadding,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: largeWidgetPadding,
                    child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: _pageController,
                        itemCount: data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                            UpcomingEventCard(
                                isLeave: false,
                                eventDate: data[index].caldate,
                                description:
                                    data[index].description,
                                daysToGo: data[index].days,
                                pageController: _pageController))))
              ],
            ),
        ))
    ]))
```

Comment: Will you plese provide more code or [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: try FractionallySizedBox

Comment: @A-E I tried using ```FractionallySizedBox``` and set the ```heightFactor``` but it will still have the problem I faced...